# Recognizing old Japanese handwriting

Tags: classical-japanese, handwriting, hentaigana

Can you please help me with recognizing this line in old Japanese handwriting?

[image: old Japanese handwriting]

As I suppose, this is:

> ?  やき ？ っすれ ？ の二

but it's most likely that I am wrong

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a famous book called ぎやどぺかどる, a translation of *[Guía de Pecadores](http://mercaba.org/Libros/LUIS%20GRANADA/INDICE.htm)* (or "[The Sinner's Guide](http://www.ewtn.com/library/SPIRIT/GRANADA.HTM)") by Jesuit mission in Japan.

It reads:

> きやとへかとる　巻の二 (voicing marks unused)
>   *Guia do Pecador - Book 2* (title in Medieval Portuguese)

What makes it hard to read is *[hentaigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hentaigana)*, now obsolete historic alternate kana, used in the line as:

> きやと
>   *or*
>   きや**登遍可**と**類** (hentaigana in original kanji forms)

---

**EDIT**:
<s>The shape of the eighth letter, which I read 其, seems rather peculiar, that more resembles hentaigana 春 or 寿 (both for す). There's a possibility that it's a typesetting error (note that the border between kana and cursive style kanji is fuzzy), or meant to be hentaigana 楚 for そ.</s>

Sorry, of course [it was 巻](http://clioz39.hi.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ships/ZClient/W34/z_list.php?title=%E5%B7%BB&resourcetype=0) :)

Comment: Hentaigana Unicode is finally out? Cool! What font are you using?

Comment: @leoboiko http://wakufactory.jp/densho/font/hentai/ Enjoy!