# What is the meaning of 巻ノ + number next to a book?

Tags: translation, kanji, katakana, orthography

What is the meaning of 巻ノ + number next to a book?

I know that

- 巻 = volume
- ノ = ?
- 七十二　= 72

So it's Volume [?] 72

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I removed my answer. I would have expected this to be read 二十七の巻, but in that case it appears to be 巻【まき】の七十二... I guess somebody else will have to explain this.

Comment: No problem, what is the meaning of  ノ? it's the same as の  but in katakana?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa yes, ノ here is the same as の.

Answer (score 6):

巻【まき】の七十二 is just [a traditional way](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34033/7810) to say "Volume 72". Were it not a ninja manga, we would normally say （第）七十二[巻]【かん】.

の is the only way to connect a noun to another in Japanese. Unlike English, [you cannot directly attach "with", "from", "by" and such to a noun unless via の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27363/7810). The の alone is thus the most ambiguous and versatile modifier with a lot of idiomatic usages. Here if literally interpreted, it would be "72 in volume" or "72 among volumes", which is a fixed way to indicate that it is the 72nd book in the series.

**PS**
Although the Japanese writing direction could be right-to-left in horizontal alignment, something like 二十七ノ巻 is hardly used as a volume number marker. ～の巻【まき】 would be usually the traditional format of title, that is, an explanation comes before の.

[image]
(an episode from the anime 忍者ハットリくん)

Comment: かんけ―ないけど　[掘]{ほり}り[出]{だ}せ　になってんねんな・・

Comment: @Chocolate あとよく見ると「掘」じゃなくて「堀」なんですね〜。昭和の大らかさを感じます（笑）

Comment: ええっ　「堀」「掘る」...ほんまや！！ 気付かんかったｗｗｗ

Answer (score 2):

卷ノ(の)七十二 can be read in two ways. The first 二十七ノ卷, this is an old way reading Japanese letters from right to left. The second 卷ノ七十二, this is a new modern way reading them from left to right. Even as a native speaker of Japanese, I am a little perplexed, and have done a little search about his Manga. The answer is: 卷ノ七十二, meaning Vol. 72.